# Enter click causes aspx page postback and Jtable fail to load

Tags: c#, asp.net, click, enter, jquery-jtable

I have been using JTable in my aspx pages and all seems well, but on a certain content page, when I try to edit or Add an item in Jtable, and by default I press Enter, the UI becomes vague.
Before pressing Enter while Updating Jtable row.
[image]

And when I press enter in order to save this:

[image]

All I want is to disable Enter click.
And I have no input tag, no form tag so that I can specify the defaultButton in the same or I can add Javascript to disable Enter press on any control as I only have Jtable and no other textbox.

Comment: try this http://webcheatsheet.com/javascript/disable_enter_key.php

Comment: And You saved my effort, this worked, Please add as an answer so that I can accept the same. +1 for the time saver. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use javascript to diable the option of enter pressing using [this](http://webcheatsheet.com/javascript/disable_enter_key.php) link